# How to Redirect to Product View Page if No option Options are Selected In magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, wishlist

i am making a guestwishlist i want to know how i can make a condtion if no product options are selected if must have to redirect me to product view page on add to cart option magento..

i did this so far

```
if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $cookieValue = explode(', ', $this->cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME));
            $cookieValue=array_filter($cookieValue);
            foreach ($cookieValue as $productId) {
                $product = $this->product->load($productId);     
                try {
                    $params = array(
                        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                        'product' => $productId, 
                        'qty'   =>1
                    );              
                    $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                    $this->cart->save();

                } catch (\Throwable $ex) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__($ex->getMessage()).' for '.$product->getName());
                }

            }
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
```